# In BLE pairing- How to share programmatically static Passkey from central(iPad) to peripheral(BLE Component)

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

When i try to connect my device(iOS Application) to my peripheral(BLE Component), it asks me a passkey (a pop-up is shown on the device). I want to send this passkey programmatically during the connection.
I'm using CBCentralManager but I can't find a way to send it programatically.
Please provide your valuable inputs and suggestion...

Thanks and Regards
-Ibrahim Sulaiman

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I need to enter the passkey without the user intervention. So I need the above functionality to be implemented.

Comment: Solution for this is really appreciated. Please provide solution ASAP